# Create useTransition custom hook using useReducer in react 17 version

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks, usetransition

I know that useTransition hook was created using a function called flushSync in react 18 version.

Can't I use this as a custom hook in react 17 version?

Due to my lack of knowledge, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The short answer is no.
I was looking for a solution too.
But, the flushSync method is introduced in React 18